# How to split ldap parameter in Django

Tags: python, django, ldap

I mapping users with django ldap. It works but my ldap 'cn' parameter contains first name and last name. I would like to split it and property assign. ex.(cn:Adam Smith)

Probably I should do in place where user is created. But I don't well know where exaclly is it.

I try split in settings.py, but it's impossible or am I wrong ?

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
     'first_name': 'cn',
}


list=cn.split(' ')

first_name = list[0]
last_name = list[1]
```

Comment: `first_name, last_name  =cn.split(' ')` if that's what you wanted

Comment: Can you provide some more code?

Comment: @Raturaj 
  ` AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=Group,dc=example", `
            ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
            )
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr='cn')

AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS = True

AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
        'first_name' : 'cn',
 'last_name' : 'cn'  } `
I want reach something like that, for example cn is equal: Adam Smith and first_name = Adam and last_name = Smith

Answer (score 0):

@Raturaj solving was quite easy but i had to search it. Last paragraph of this article helped me. https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-add-ldap-and-active-directory-authentication-to-django/. And knowledge how to init signals.py file, its easy to gind it on stack overflow.

and my code if this article will be out of date:

signals.py:

```
import re
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_auth_ldap.backend import populate_user, LDAPBackend


@receiver(populate_user, sender=LDAPBackend)
def ldap_auth_handler(user, ldap_user, **kwargs):

    list = user.first_name.split(' ')
    user.first_name= list[0]
    user.last_name = list[1]


    user.save()
```

and in settings.py

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
        'first_name' : 'cn',
 }
```